# Good Python programming practice for ending a loop on finding an item in a list

Tags: python

You need to iterate through a list to find the first occurrence of an item that satisfies a condition. Such an item may be in the list or it may not. If the item is found, you should end the loop immediately and print 'found'. If the item is not found you should print 'not found'.

The question is which of these two solutions is better 'programming practice' and why? If you think neither is good programming practice, please include a better solution.

Note that this is a question about programming practice, what is/isn't generally considered good programming practice and why.

Solution 1:

```
for item in lst:
  if condition(item):
    print('found')
    break
else:
  print('not found')
```

Solution 2:

```
i = 0
found = False
while i < len(lst) and not found:
  if condition(lst[i]):
    found = True
  i += 1
if found:
  print('found')
else:
  print('not found')
```

Comment: As you don't tagged a y language, but your example is in python, you must also consider, that your first snippet `for ... else`  doesn't have an equivalent in many other languages ... Other than that, this s highly opinion based, and the answer may also vary in different situations ...

Comment: Iterator one (Solution 1), Because its easy to read.

Comment: @derpirscher If edited the question to show it's Python. Perhaps you could elucidate on which solution would be appropriate in which situation.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is exactly as you describe (ie just output "found" or "not found") in python the `for .. else` construct works fine and is the (imo) a very nice construct that I would like to have in other languages too, because it eliminates the "clumsyness" of having an additional variable just to denote, whether an element was found or not.

If you need additional access to the found element, I'd prefer something like the following

```
for x in test_list:
    if condition(x):
        break
else:
    x = None
    
if x == None:
    print("not found")
else:
    print("found it")
    print(x)
```

Furthermore, many languages also have some sort of `collection.firdFirstWith(condition)` or `collection.findFirstIndexWith(condition)`. So instead of implementing the loop yourself you can just make use of these functions.

Comment: You mentioned that this question was highly opinion-based, and that was really my point. Is 'good programming practice' just an opinion or is there something definite we can say about advantages and disadvantages of a particular method, and this one in particular?